# WPF DataGridCell BorderThickness=0 doesn't work

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridcell

DataGridColumnHeader.BorderThickness=0 works for me, but not DataGridRow or DataGridCell, any thought?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 0 1" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved by setting `GridLinesVisibility` property to `None`.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" DataGrid.GridLinesVisibility="None">
    ...
```

You could play with the following snippet to understand which part of `DataGrid` is affected by the `BorderThickness` settings- there are 3 border styles, each has a different color.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" >
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 0 1" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! can you also help me on this? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163775/wpf-datagridcolumnwidth-doesnt-work-well-when-printvisual)